# White space between title of question and content of question

Tags: support, design, advertising

What is with the whitespace between a question's title and its content? I do not have this when I post on Stack Overflow:

[image: Notice the whitespace?]

By the way, the question above is not mine (the URL is https://superuser.com/q/606969/222470).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine to me over here. My guess is you have an ad-blocker turned on, since that's where the ad would go. [Ads are hidden once you reach 200 reputation points](https://superuser.com/privileges/reduced-ads). Since you have >300 rep on Stack Overflow, and <200 on Super User, that explains why you're seeing it here and not there.

If you turn off your ad-blocker, then I'm guessing a banner image will appear in that space.

Comment: The only problem is, the ads removed by earning enough reputation only remove the ads at the top and bottom and not the right. I do not want ANY ads whatsoever, so is it possible that I can pay to buy out of them, or is there a good enough CSS filter that can remove the space left behind for the ad?

Comment: @gparyani which ads at the right are you referring to? The only ads I ever see on SU or SO are in-house ads (e.g. for other sites, community promotion ads, SO careers, etc.). They're all unobtrusive and essentially just links to other sites on the Stack Exchange network. I don't think it's appropriate for you to ask us to write an ad filter for you, especially when the ads are as benign as they are. It's up to you to choose between seeing the ads or seeing the blank space, but please consider that bandwidth bills, servers, and developers don't pay themselves.

Comment: That's why I asked about buying out of ads.

Comment: @gparyani I am not aware of any way to buy out of ads.